# http status code 200 in browser, but 403 in http status checker, why?

Tags: http-status-code-403

http status checker: https://httpstatus.io/ 
or 
http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/?url=capefearadventures.com&useragent=8&protocol=11

url: capefearadventures.com

Both checkers return 403, but if I pull up the site in any browser it works fine returning 200.

Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: Is this your website? Have you looked at the logs? How about using a command-line tool like `curl` to see what's going on?

Comment: the website is mine but it's on shared hosting. Their support said "it works fine" and that was the end of it. I don't think I have access to either logs or any kind or tools outside of their interface.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to access the firewall logs and the requests from http status checkers were deemed as DDOS22 - DDOS attemps, therefore blocked. I added their IP to whitelist and the request went through just fine returning 200! Thanks for the pointer!